# How to parse list of lists using Gson

Tags: gson

I have a JSON that looks like this:

```
{
     "1": [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2},{"id": 3}, {"id": 4}],
     "2": [{"id": 5}, {"id": 6}],
     "3": [{"id": 3}, {"id": 4}]
}
```

I would like it be parsed into

```
List<List<Integer>> list
```

or

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map
```

How should I use Gson to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least two options: imperative and the Gson way.

In the imperative option, you can simply parse the whole JSON tree for the given JSON using Gson facilities step by step:

```java
final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        // any custom Gson configuration here
        .create();
final Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for ( final Entry<String, JsonElement> e : gson.fromJson(JSON, JsonElement.class).getAsJsonObject().entrySet() ) {
    // parseInt() ignores additional type adapters in Gson
    final Integer key = gson.fromJson(e.getKey(), Integer.class);
    final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    final Iterable<JsonObject> asJsonArray = (Iterable) e.getValue().getAsJsonArray();
    for ( final JsonObject el : asJsonArray ) {
        final Integer integer = gson.fromJson(el.get("id"), Integer.class);
        list.add(integer);
    }
    map.put(key, list);
}
out.println(map);
```

A bit dirty, isn't it?. The output:

> {1=[1, 2, 3, 4], 2=[5, 6], 3=[3, 4]}

An alternative is making a custom fake DTO that would be a special marker for Gson `TypeToken`s in order to bind JSON deserialization more precisely. For example:

```java
abstract class FakeInt {

    private FakeInt() {
        throw new AssertionError("Not meant to be instantiated");
    }

}
```

This is an abstract class with a private constructor throwing an error, so it cannot be instantiated outside. And it should never be, it's just a marker.

```java
final class FakeIntDeserializer
        implements JsonDeserializer<Integer> {

    private static final JsonDeserializer<Integer> fakeIntDeserializer = new FakeIntDeserializer();

    private FakeIntDeserializer() {
    }

    static JsonDeserializer<Integer> getFakeIntDeserializer() {
        return fakeIntDeserializer;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer deserialize(final JsonElement json, final Type type, final JsonDeserializationContext context) {
        final JsonElement idElement = json.getAsJsonObject().get("id");
        return context.deserialize(idElement, Integer.class);
    }

}
```

This deserializer is aware of the JSON array elements having the `id` property: once it's obtained from the parent object, the `idElement` is delegated to a downstream parser to extract an `Integer` value. Despite it's possible to use `idElement.getAsInt()`, `idElement` is delegated in order to respect the whole `Gson` configuration (you can have special rules for the `Integer` class). And how the fake DTO class and its JSON deserializer work together:

```java
final Type integerToFakeIntListType = new TypeToken<Map<Integer, List<FakeInt>>>() {
}.getType();
final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(FakeInt.class, getFakeIntDeserializer())
        .create();
final Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = gson.fromJson(JSON, integerToFakeIntListType);
out.println(map);
```

Note that the `Gson` instance is built with a sort of a hack or a cheat: the `FakeInt` class is bound to the custom deserializer that can only return `Integer` values or `null`. Once the types and their deserializers are bound, the `Gson` instance is ready to use and the given JSON can be parsed *as if it were a map of integers to lists of integers*. Exactly the same output is as follows:

> {1=[1, 2, 3, 4], 2=[5, 6], 3=[3, 4]}